# Need to download 90MB+ xlsx file, cannot save it on the server. Can I stream it to a client

Tags: django, sockets, uwsgi, openpyxl, file-descriptor

I have Django running on an Nginx Webserver, with uwsgi as application server.
I need to generate a large .xlsx file by combining multiple smaller ones. Then that file needs to be downloaded to a client.

After googling a lot, I have not been able to find anything that really answers my question, so I am asking here.

I am using an openpyxl WriteOnly Worksheet. Upon trying to save the worksheet the process always gets killed.

My question is, whether I can stream the workbook to the client via a uwsgi socket and save it there.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide some sample code for an implementation, that can save or stream the file to a client!